# How to screen capture at window application with scrollable using java code

Tags: java, scroll, screenshot, awtrobot

I'd like to screen capture Windows applications (including scrolls) in a way that is possible, such as Java's Robot Library or User32.

So far, what I've found is processing the full size or scrolling on web pages, but not including scrolling on Windows applications.

//Can I capture the screen I want by adding scrolls to the code below?

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class ScreenShotUsingJNA {
    public static void createScreenCapture() throws AWTException, IOException {
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
        
        Dimension resolution = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        
        int hWnd = User32.instance.FindWindowA(null, "eclipse-sts window");
        WindowInfo w = getWindowInfo(hWnd);
        User32.instance.SetForegroundWindow(w.hwnd);
        BufferedImage createScreenCapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0, 0, resolution.width, resolution.height));
        ImageIO.write(createScreenCapture, "png", new File("save file info with path"));

        // listAllWindows();
    }

    private static void listAllWindows() throws AWTException, IOException {
        final List<WindowInfo> inflList = new ArrayList<WindowInfo>();
        final List<Integer> order = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int top = User32.instance.GetTopWindow(0);
        while (top != 0) {
            order.add(top);
            top = User32.instance.GetWindow(top, User32.GW_HWNDNEXT);
        }

        User32.instance.EnumWindows(new WndEnumProc() {
            public boolean callback(int hWnd, int lParam) {
                WindowInfo info = getWindowInfo(hWnd);
                inflList.add(info);
                return true;
            }

        }, 0);
        Collections.sort(inflList, new Comparator<WindowInfo>() {
            public int compare(WindowInfo o1, WindowInfo o2) {
                return order.indexOf(o1.hwnd) - order.indexOf(o2.hwnd);
            }
        });
        for (WindowInfo w : inflList) {
            System.out.println(w);
        }
    }

    public static  WindowInfo getWindowInfo(int hWnd) {
        RECT r = new RECT();
        User32.instance.GetWindowRect(hWnd, r);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        User32.instance.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, buffer, buffer.length);
        String title = Native.toString(buffer);
        WindowInfo info = new WindowInfo(hWnd, r, title);
        return info;
    }

    public static interface WndEnumProc extends StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback {
        boolean callback(int hWnd, int lParam);
    }

    public static interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        public static final String SHELL_TRAY_WND = "Shell_TrayWnd";
        public static final int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
        public static final int MIN_ALL = 0x1a3;
        public static final int MIN_ALL_UNDO = 0x1a0;

        final User32 instance = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

        boolean EnumWindows(WndEnumProc wndenumproc, int lParam);

        boolean IsWindowVisible(int hWnd);

        int GetWindowRect(int hWnd, RECT r);

        void GetWindowTextA(int hWnd, byte[] buffer, int buflen);

        int GetTopWindow(int hWnd);

        int GetWindow(int hWnd, int flag);

        boolean ShowWindow(int hWnd);

        boolean BringWindowToTop(int hWnd);

        int GetActiveWindow();

        boolean SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);

        int FindWindowA(String winClass, String title);

        long SendMessageA(int hWnd, int msg, int num1, int num2);

        final int GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;
    }

    public static class RECT extends Structure {
        public int left, top, right, bottom;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            List<String> order = new ArrayList<>();
            order.add("left");
            order.add("top");
            order.add("right");
            order.add("bottom");
            return order;
        }
    }

    public static class WindowInfo {
        int hwnd;
        RECT rect;
        String title;

        public WindowInfo(int hwnd, RECT rect, String title) {
            this.hwnd = hwnd;
            this.rect = rect;
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("(%d,%d)-(%d,%d) : \"%s\"", rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, title);
        }
    }
}
```